# Is there any PCL build with glut instead of VTK?

Tags: linux, arm, glut, vtk, point-cloud-library

I am build PCL on several platforms (windows, Linux, ARM Linux, Andoid, ios and OS X). VTK is always giving me hard time building on the different platforms. Is there any PCL build that uses GLUT rather than VTK?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no GLUT version of the PCLViewer and related things. However, if you can live without `pcl_visualization`, you could build PCL without the modules that use VTK.